# Lifetime issue in default trait implementation

Tags: generics, rust, traits, lifetime

I'm trying to make a generic trait where one of the methods uses a default implementation that wraps the rest to reduce boilerplate.

Here's a minimal reproduction:

```
trait ReadFormat<'a, 'b: 'a, Arg: 'b, T: 'static>: Sized {
    fn new(c: &'a mut Cursor<'a>, arg: Arg) -> Self;
    fn into_format(self) -> SResult<T>;
    fn read(bytes: &'b [u8], arg: Arg) -> SResult<T> {
        let c = &mut Cursor::new(bytes);
        let r = Self::new(c, arg);
        let f = r.into_format();
        f
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error

```
61 | trait ReadFormat<'a, 'b: 'a, Arg: 'b, T: 'static>: Sized {
   |                  -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
65 |         let c = &mut Cursor::new(bytes);
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
66 |         let r = Self::new(c, arg);
   |                 ----------------- argument requires that borrow lasts for `'a`
...
69 |     }
   |     - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
```

I've tried various combinations of lifetimes, but none of them work. In general, I don't understand why it expects Self to live after read returns when it's consumed by into_format and T owns all of it's data.

If I copy-paste the exact same code into a concrete implementation and replace Self::new with Reader::new it compiles.

```
impl<'a, 'b: 'a> ReadFormat<'a, 'b, (), ()> for Reader<'a> {
    ..
    fn read(bytes: &'b [u8], arg: ()) -> SResult<()> {
        let c = &mut Cursor::new(bytes);
        let r = Reader::new(c, arg);
        let f = r.into_format();
        f
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why it expects Self to live after read returns

It doesn't; the problem is with `c` how long `c` lives.

The signature of `new()` expects a reference that lives for `'a`, which is a lifetime parameter declared *on the trait*. Therefore, for any specific usage of the trait, if you call `new()`, the `c` reference must be valid up until you stop using the trait implementation. But, `c` is a local variable in `read()`, which is *inside* the trait implementation, so it doesn't live that long.

Here is a non-trait example of the same mistake, which fails for the same reason:

```rust
struct Cursor {}
struct Foo<'a> {
    c: &'a mut Cursor,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn read() {
        let c = &mut Cursor {};
        let _ = Self { c };
    }
}
```

In order to avoid this problem, you must either

- not have any lifetime parameters on the trait, or
- don't make `read()` a trait function — that allows it to have a more flexible relationship to the involved lifetimes.

---

Another problem you have is that the type `&'a mut Cursor<'a>` — or more generally, `&'a mut Something<'a>` — is essentially always wrong. Using the same lifetime for a mutable reference and for the *contents* of the reference creates two outlives constraints:

- `&'a mut Cursor<'a>` must be valid for (must outlive) `'a`, or it would not be an `&'a ...`.
- `'a` must outlive `Cursor<'a>`, or the `Cursor`s could have dangling references in them.

The consequence of using the same lifetime in both places is that the `Cursor` becomes borrowed *for the rest of its existence*, which is probably not what you want.

The solution is to use separate lifetimes for the reference and the referent.

---

Putting all this together:

```rust
struct Cursor<'b>(&'b [u8]);
impl<'b> Cursor<'b> {
    fn new(bytes: &'b [u8]) -> Self {
        Self(bytes)
    }
}

trait ReadFormat<'cur, 'bytes, Arg, T>: Sized {
    fn new(c: &'cur mut Cursor<'bytes>, arg: Arg) -> Self;
    fn into_format(self) -> Result<T, ()>;
}

fn read<'b, R, Arg, T>(bytes: &'b [u8], arg: Arg) -> Result<T, ()>
where
    // for<'cur> means this trait can be used with ANY cursor lifetime
    R: for<'cur> ReadFormat<'cur, 'b, Arg, T>
{
    let c = &mut Cursor::new(bytes);
    let r = R::new(c, arg);
    r.into_format()
}
```

You can simplify things further if you make `ReadFormat::new()` take an owned `Cursor` instead of an `&mut` reference; that would eliminate the need for a [higher-rank trait bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) for the cursor lifetime, by not having a cursor lifetime at all. But maybe that doesn't serve your goals.

---

By the way, a couple of hints for the next time you're asking a question or even just troubleshooting:

- Your "minimal reproduction" is not *complete*; it didn't give a definition for the `Cursor` type. That didn't seem to matter here, but it can.
- In "… the following error", you cut off the actual primary error message — the line that starts with `error: ...`. It's important to include that message, and even more important to *read* that message. The messages on following lines are meant to be understood as further details after the primary message, not stand on their own.